# How to add custom header when creating bucket using Boto3?

Tags: python, boto3

I can create a bucket using [these parameters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.create). But none of them is a custom header. It's also said that [boto3 will not support it](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/216) because S3 does not currently allow setting arbitrary headers on buckets or objects.

But in my case. I am using Cloudian as storage. It supports `x-gmt-policyid` this policy determines how data in the bucket will be distributed and protected through either replication or erasure coding.

Any idea how to inject custom header to boto bucket creation?

```py
s3_resource.create_bucket(Bucket='foo-1')
```

My last two options:

1) to fork botocore and add this functionality, but I saw they use [loaders.py](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/master/botocore/loaders.py) that read everything from json file, and it seems a bit complicated for a beginner.

2) or maybe I need to use pure python implementation using `request` module to create s3 bucket.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is to fetch S3 compatible cloudian API directly. Signing the request is very complicated, so I use the help of [requests-aws4auth](https://github.com/sam-washington/requests-aws4auth) library. I tried other libs but failed.

example to create bucket with clodian `x-gmt-policyid` value:

```
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

endpoint = "http://awesome-bucket.my-s3.net"
auth = AWS4Auth(
    "00ac60d1a669fakekey",
    "S2/x9sRvb1Jys9n+fakekey",
    "eu-west-1",
    "s3",
)

headers = {
    "x-gmt-policyid": "9f934425b7f5de611c32fakeid",
    "x-amz-acl": "public-read",
}

response = requests.put(endpoint, auth=auth, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```